# MVC 5 Additional column for foreign key value related to virtual list

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship

I'm working on a simple project just to get familiar with MVC 5 and EntityFramework 6. I read tutorials available on the internet ([like this one](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)) and I think I'm  slowly starting to get a grip on it, but there is something I just can't understand. Lets say I have two simple objects like

```
  public class Player
  {
     public int ID {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}

     [ForeignKey("Team")]
     public int TeamID {get; set;}
     public virtual Team Team {get; set;}

  }
```

and

```
  public class Team
  {
     public int ID {get; set;}

     [Display(Name = "Team Leader")]
     [ForeignKey("Player")]
     public int? PlayerID {get; set;}

     //some other properties
     public virtual Player Player {get; set;}
     public virtual ICollection<Player> Players {get; set;}
  }
```

Now when I create tables basing on those models in a local database, a new column is added to the Player table. The column is added automatically and is called Team_ID. This is strange beacuse I already have this column (named TeamID) but Entity is somehow ignoring it and adds its own.

**My question is**, what should I do to prevent Entity from adding this additional column (if its possible)? Am I doing something wrong? Maybe it is because of the Team Leader foreign key?

**P.S.1** When doing some additional research I noticed that when I have a collection of 'A' objects in a 'B' model and I don't have a foreign key of 'B' in the 'A' model the column is also automatically added to the 'A' table.

**P.S.2** As I tought, removing the Team Leader foreign key solves the problem. But I cant have this navigation removed! What should I do?

Comment: Ok I was right about the Team Leader FK. It seems that the EF is confused because of these two FK in Team model. That is why it generates a column to be sure that I have navigation property in Players refering to the Players collection. To tell EF that it's already there i used an  [InverseProperty("Team")] on the collection. Works fine. For more about those kinds of relations go [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Using convention pattern you can do something like:

```
 public int TeamId {get; set;}
 public virtual Team Team {get; set;}
```

Using `[ForeignKey]`, you should add it to virtual property like this (not to the ID property):

```
public int TeamID {get; set;}
[ForeignKey("TeamID")]
public virtual Team Team {get; set;}
```

There you have some tips: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: According to the tutorial link i provided in the question the foreign key attribute can be also added  to the property (chech the OfficeAssignment model). Either way this doesn't solve the problem. I think that the tables relation isn't well defined since i have one-to-one and one-to-many raleation. That is why when I remove Team Leader all works. Maybe Fluet Api is a solution?

Comment: In many cases FluentApi is a solution - in this, it'll be too.